# How to read a digital certificate in a web application? (LAMP)

Tags: python, apache, cryptography, openssl

Is it possible to develop a web page that reads digital certificates available in the browser with Python? For example using pyOpenSSL?

I explain further:

I'd like to develop a web page that prompts the user and asks him to choose one of the digital certificates available in his browser and then prints the public information contained in it (first name, last name, email, expiration date, ecc).

I know how to extract the information from a digital certificate that is present on the hard drive using the command line (openssl) or with a python script (pyopenssl), but how to do the same for a web application? Does the user need to upload the public key of his digital certificate?
I suppose it has to be done with Apache?

Any suggestion is much appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT:

I would like to find more info about how to make something like this in flash (if possible):
http://services.viafirma.com/viafirma/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the browser itself has access to certain set of certificates (usually system certificate store + some certificate store, specific to browser), it won't let the remote system access them easily.

One way to read certificates located on the client computer is create some helper object (ActiveX control, Java applet, flash applet) and embed them into the web page. Then this helper object can try to get access to user's certificates. ActiveX control, being the native code (for Windows) can access system certificate storage (granted that it has necessary permissions configured in browser and on the client's system). With Java applet or Flash applet you are limited to certificates in files (and even then security restrictions can apply).

Without knowing what you are going to do with the certificate it's hard to say further, what can be done.

Comment: Can you not use the SunMSCAPI provider to see windows key store certificates from a Java applet?

Comment: @Petey you can if permissions allow and the provider is available (and if I understand it right, it was not in Java 5 which is still in use), yet this still requires an applet. Thanks for reminder though.

Comment: is it possible to develop something like this with flash?
http://services.viafirma.com/viafirma/

Comment: @nemesisdesign yes, it's possible. We implemented solution for distributed signing with client-side modules in flash, activex and java and server-side in .NET or Delphi. See my profile for details and contact info.  Also I can't say for sure, but it seems that the site you reference can be using our SecureBlackbox components.

Comment: @Eugene thanks for the info, Flash sounds interesting as I know a bit of actionscript but I can't find anything about it. Have any example of application to check or any information about how to implement something like that? The app in this case is just a personal student project.

Comment: @nemesisdesign It's not trivial. There's as3crypto library available for flash, but it's lacking several important things which we had to write (I don't know  details) or rewrite. So it's really a significant amount of work, especially for a student project. And server-side part, as I understand, also needs work (this part depends on details of your project though).

Comment: @nemesisdesign I'd say it the following way: if it were that easy, the market would be full of solutions for distributed signing and verification, but so far ours seems to be the only one widely available.

Comment: it seems there's no info at all about this task!
I have figured out how to extract the information from a digital certificate with openssl and pyopenssl, but I still don't understand how is it possible to create a web app that can find the certificates in the browser! Is there any article or information about it?

Comment: @nemesis we invented and implemented our scheme ourselves, so I don't know if there's a description of something similar in the internet.

Comment: I found out Apache + mod_ssl work quite well. I can use PHP or Python to retrieve the environment variables with the info about the certificate.